Looking for a chain like view that surrounds the three edges of screen in android
Here is what I want to implement in android app which will run in API 28 and onwards.
I want to create a view that starts from top left corner of screen goes vertically down to bottom left then takes 90 degree turn and runs to bottom right corner then another 90 degree turn to go to to top right corner of screen where it ends.
So, it should be like a flexible chute.
I want to display list of numbers in it.
There will be a button in center of screen which when pressed will give a new number.
I will add this new number to the chute , if the chute is filled completely then I will remove the first number from start so that rest of numbers will shift and there will be empty space at top right corner in which my new number will appear.
I cannot figure out which view will be helpful in this case ?
Please let me know if more information is needed so that I can improve my question.
Thanks.
